# Highchart: How to graph from Radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

being new to the JavaScript and Highcharts, I am in need of help. An example or reference to documentation will be really helpful.
So, what I am trying to do is to create a survey of about 10 questions with answers such as, Yes, No, and Both in Radio-Button format.

When the users select these answers, I want it to be graphed, and from looking around, I believe that Highcharts seems to be the most neat-looking library to use.

How may I accomplish this?

**In summary**, user selects answers to the questions, and when they press the "submit" button, the code should count how many Yes, No, and Both there are and draw a bargraph.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<body>

<form action="first question">
<p>Would you choose an Apple?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="yes"> Yes<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="no"> No<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="other"> Both
</form>

<form action="second question">
<p>Would you choose a Banana?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="yes"> Yes<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="no"> No<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="other"> Both
</form>

</body>

<button type = button> Submit </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Store your yes, no, and both in yesCount, noCount, bothCount. Give your yes's, no's and both's a seperate identifier so you can selected the all and see how many have the checked attribute.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Yes/No'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Subtitle Here'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Votes'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 80,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Yes',
            data: [yesCount]
        }, {
            name: 'No',
            data: [noCount]
        },{
            name: 'Both',
            data: [bothCount]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a jsfiddle fiddle or code snippet example please